# Turning this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a graph, which shows stats for the latest 7 days. They are shown like this:

> Today - 17-09 - 16-09 - 15-09 - 14-09 - 13-09 - 12-09

The PHP looks like this:

```
$days = array('Today');
for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $days[$i] = date('d-m', strtotime('-' . ($i + 0) . ' day'));
}
```

My question is, how can I do so it will look like this:

> 12-09 - 13-09 - 14-09 - 15-09 - 16-09 - 17-09 - Today

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$days = array_reverse($days);
```

Otherwise you can generate it in reverse order:

```
 $days = array();
    for ($i=6; $i>=1;$i--)
    {
      $days[] = date('d-m', strtotime('-'.($i+0).' day'));
    }
 $days[] = 'Today';
```

Comment: With this, it just looks like: 12-09 - 14-09 - Today - 17-09 - 15-09 - 13-09

Comment: @Oliver: Then the array is not the way you say it is.

Comment: Sorry, the first one with the reverse() did not work. The 2nd solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try:

```
    for ($i=0; $i<6;$i++)
    {
      $days[6-$i] = date('d-m', strtotime('-'.(6-$i+0).' day'));
    }
 $days[6] = array('Today');
```